# Laravel 8.83.27, Undefined property: stdClass::$image (view: /Application/../..)

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have two tables:

- `items`

  - `id`
  - `name`
  - `description`
  - `created_at`
  - `update_at`
- `images`

  - `id`
  - `name`
  - `item_id`
  - `created_at`
  - `updated_at`

I did build a one-to-one relationship between the `Item` model and `Image` model.

##### `Item` model

```php
<?php 

namespace App/Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use App\Models\Image;

class Item extends Model
{
    use HashFactory;

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Image::class, "item_id");
    }
}
```

##### `Image` model

```php
<?php

namespace App/Models;

use App\Models\Item;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Item extends Model
{
    use HashFactory;

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }
}
```

##### Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Reuquest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class RootController extends Controller
{
    $items = DB::table("items")->get();

    return view("index", ["items" => $items]);
}
```

In The view I wanted to show the image name of each item, therefore I proceeded the following way,

```html
<div>
   @foreach($items as item)
       <span>{{ $item->image->name }}</span>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

I, despite my checkings and analyses, couldn't figure out where I was wrong in this code.

Comment: Don't use the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) but [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)

Comment: You must do `Items::all()` instead of `DB::table....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = DB::table("items")->get();
```

should be:

```
$items = Item::all();
```

Using the `DB` facade instead of the Eloquent model means none of your model's functionality or settings apply to the resulting query.